# Issue with Sidebar and Content Rendering in Material

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've implemented a sidebar using Material UI components. However, I'm facing an issue where the content I have within the home.js file seems to be going under the sidebar when I try to render it on the page.

I'm using the default Material UI components and styling, and I haven't customized anything

How to properly structure the components to ensure that the content doesn't overlap with the sidebar?